# How to interactively test the executable of an NPM Node.js package during development without constantly reinstalling the package?

Tags: node.js, npm

Consider a simple sample module [like this one](https://github.com/cirosantilli/browserify-hello-world/tree/1325e6807daed544fa3d1e558ca9fdf2c9995a6d).

The package exposes a dummy function something like:

index.js

```
const uniq = require('uniq');
function myfunc() {
  return uniq([1, 2, 2, 3]).join(' ');
}
exports.myfunc = myfunc;
```

Then, an executable uses the function:

browserify-hello-world

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const browserify_hello_world = require('browserify-hello-world');
console.log(browserify_hello_world.myfunc());
```

The package publishes both the `index.js` and the executable with:

package.json

```
  "bin": {
    "browserify-hello-world": "browserify-hello-world"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uniq": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

My question is, how to test the `browserify-hello-world` executable interactively during development?

If I just clone the repository and do:

```
npm install
./browserify-hello-world
```

then it fails with:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'browserify-hello-world'
```

because as documented at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install `install` does not install the current package itself under `node_modules`.

I got it close to working perfectly with:

```
npm link
npm link browserify-hello-world
./browserify-hello-world
```

which runs correctly because:

- `npm link`:

  - creates a symlink from the global package install: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/broserify-hello-world` to the source directory
  - runs `npm install` on the source directory, which creates `node_modules` with all dependencies
- `npm link browserify-hello-world` creates a symlink from `node_modules/browserify-hello-world` to the global directory `~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/broserify-hello-world`

which works well because everything is done with symlinks, so that updates to the local package are immediately visible to the executable.

The only downside of this method, besides the inconvenience of typing all those commands after install, is that afterwards during development, if I need to install a new dependency into the project, e.g. with:

```
npm install vaca
```

then that breaks by symlinks for some reason: `node_modules/broserify-hello-world` is gone, and I am forced once again to do:

```
npm link
npm link browserify-hello-world
```

Note that doind just `npm link browserify-hello-world` above does not work and fails with:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'uniq'
```

because the dependency of our package, `uniq`, was also removed by `npm install vaca`.

Is there a way to avoid redoing the `link` process after every new install?

The `npm-safe-install` module might exist to address this problem: https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install but when I tried it with:

```
npm install -g npm-safe-install
npm-safe-install vaca
```

although it did keep my `node_modules/borwserify-hello-world` symlink, it still removed the dependency `uniq`. I asked about that at: https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install/issues/4

Related threads:

- https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/533
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357144/npm-package-development-run-executable
- https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2380
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1573
- https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/8501

Tested with: npm 6.12.0, Node.js 10.15.1 installed with [NVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/971612#971612) and `npm-safe-install` 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has been resolved and changes are published with some added features. Changes are available in `npm-safe-install@1.1.0`. Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks!! Worth mentioning that resolution was done in response to: https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install/issues/4 at https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install/pull/5